# Apache proxy - split SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN value and set header

Tags: ssl-certificate, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, apache2

I have configured on Apache proxy mutual SSL with

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth 3
```

The configuration and communication is working like expected.

Now I would like to send from Apache proxy to backend information from Common Name field in Subject DN from client certificate. The CN field has fromat of `CN=[HexString1]-[HexString2]`.
What I would like to do is to:

```
RequestHeader set HexString1 %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN_HexString1}
RequestHeader set HexString2 %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN_HexString2}
```

I was looking into mod_rewrite but it doesn't seem to help me in the splitting CN to achieve my goal.

Is there any way how to configure it in Apache proxy?